# MPNet output to visualization

Tags: data-visualization, networks

I've been using igraph and statnet to do most of my network analysis, but I am trying to replicate results that I use MPNet (an expansion to [PNet](http://sna.unimelb.edu.au/PNet)) in order to perform some simulations on a multi-level network. I'm hoping someone has experience with PNet or MPNet and can offer a suggestion.

I've run a few simulations of small networks, and the output for any specific simulation doesn't really lend itself to being visualized easily in igraph and statnet outside of manually inputting the networks and visual attributes of each vertex. This is problematic for me because I want to simulate large-ish (n>20 in each level) networks.

*However,* it does appear that the output is intended to be visualized by the way it is written (see below), but I'm unsure what program it's intended for and cannot find much existing MPNet (or PNet) help online.

**My question is this:** is there a way to use MPNet output for a specific simulation to visualize the network that is being simulated without manually entering in each network and visual attributes into some package? 
Or in other words, did MPNet designers have a destination in mind with their output?

---

The following picture is a quick MSPaint rendition of this 10 vertex multi-level simulated network (because we all need a little MSPaint in our lives):
[image]

I have four output text files for a specific simulation (sorry in advance for the huge amount of output):

Network A:

```
  *vertices 5
1 "" box ic Blue bc Black
2 "" box ic Blue bc Black
3 "" box ic Blue bc Black
4 "" box ic Blue bc Black
5 "" box ic Blue bc Black
*matrix
0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 1 0 

Density 0.7000
Degree Distribution(s)
Mean degree 1.4000
Stddev  1.9105
Skewness    0.8547
Clustering coefficent(s)
Global  0.8000
```

Network B:

```
*vertices 5
1 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
2 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
3 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
4 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
5 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
*matrix
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 
1 1 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 

Density 0.5000
Degree Distribution(s)
Mean degree 1.0000
Stddev  1.6583
Skewness    1.2718
Clustering coefficent(s)
Global  0.3750
```

Network X:

```
*vertices 10 5
1 "" box ic Blue bc Black
2 "" box ic Blue bc Black
3 "" box ic Blue bc Black
4 "" box ic Blue bc Black
5 "" box ic Blue bc Black
6 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
7 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
8 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
9 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
10 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
*edges
1 6
1 9
3 7
3 8
3 9
3 10
4 6
4 7
4 8
5 8
5 9

Density 0.4400
Degree Distribution(s)
Mean degree A   2.2000
Stddev A    1.4832
Skewness A  -0.2648
Mean degree B   2.2000
Stddev B    0.8367
Skewness B  -0.2459
Clustering coefficent
Global  0.2667
```

Network M:

```
*vertices 10
1 "" box ic Blue bc Black
2 "" box ic Blue bc Black
3 "" box ic Blue bc Black
4 "" box ic Blue bc Black
5 "" box ic Blue bc Black
6 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
7 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
8 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
9 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
10 "" ellipse ic Red bc Black
*edges
1 2 1 c Blue
1 3 1 c Blue
1 4 1 c Blue
1 5 1 c Blue
3 4 1 c Blue
3 5 1 c Blue
4 5 1 c Blue
6 8 1 c Red
7 8 1 c Red
7 10 1 c Red
8 9 1 c Red
8 10 1 c Red
1 6 1 c Black
1 9 1 c Black
3 7 1 c Black
3 8 1 c Black
3 9 1 c Black
3 10 1 c Black
4 6 1 c Black
4 7 1 c Black
4 8 1 c Black
5 8 1 c Black
5 9 1 c Black
```

*Also, if someone has enough reputation and feels the need to add the tags PNet and/or MPNet to this post so that it could be more specific, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualised these outputted networks in Pajek (which is free) 
See the Pajek website & manual on the data format if any additional cleaning of the file is needed.

http://pajek.imfm.si/doku.php